# Java 8 GroupBy and transform result to a list

Tags: java-8, grouping, transformation

Hello I have to group by multiple fields and make a summary by one of these files, thereafter I have to work with this result and make some more transformations my problem is that I'm getting a complex structure after the grouping and it's not easy to work with this items. This is my code:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<LocalDateTime, Map<String, Double>>>> processed = null;

processed = itemsToProcess
          .stream()
          .collect(groupingBy(entity::getId,
              groupingBy(entity::getType,
                  groupingBy(entity::getCreateDate,
                      groupingBy(entity::getCode,
                          summingDouble(entity::getPay))))));
```

The objective of this grouping is the summary of the pays but thereafter I I have to do some transformations with this `processed` structure, my doubt if is there is a way to transform this in a simple list in order to make more easy this task?

My input is basically a list of:

```
List<Person> itemsToProcess= new ArrayList<>();


    @JsonInclude
    public class Person extends Entity<Person > {
    
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    
      /* File line content */
      private String id;
      private String type;
      private LocalDateTime createDate;
      private String code;
      private double pay;
      private String city
      private String company
    }
```

The output that I'm looking for is the summary of the pay field grouped by {id,type,createDate,pay}

example if I have the next values

```
Id   type    createdDAte    Code   pay    more fields....
1     0         today        BC    500     
1     0         today        BC    600
2     0         today        BC    600
2     0         today        BC    300
3     0         today        BC    300

The result must be:

Id   type    createdDAte    Code   pay    more fields....
1     0         today        BC    1100
2     0         today        BC    900
3     0         today        BC    300
```

Comment: Do you really need all groupingBy or only by Id?

Comment: No, the groping must be done by all the fields (id,type,createDate,code) and finally sum by the pay.

Comment: Did you understand its nested grouping not groupingby (id,type,createDate,code) ? Can you show for your input what is your expected output with an example ?

Comment: No, sorry it's the first time that I'm using this feature.

Comment: I added an example of what I'm looking for, thanks!

Comment: How more fields will merged ?

Comment: They will be merged as the came. I'm just wonder about the (id,type,createDate,code) fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Collectors.toMap` to Map by that four properties and merging the same group person objects and creating a new one using the constructor.

```
List<Person> processed = 
      new ArrayList<>(
        itemsToProcess
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            i -> Arrays.asList(i.getId(), i.getType(), i.getCreateDate(), i.getCode()),
            i -> i,
            (a, b) -> new Person(a.getId(), a.getType(), a.getCreateDate(), a.getCode(),
                a.getPay() + b.getPay())))
        .values());
```

Output:

```
Person [id=2, type=0, createDate=2020-08-18T12:26:15.616034800, code=BC, pay=900.0]
Person [id=3, type=0, createDate=2020-08-18T12:26:15.616034800, code=BC, pay=300.0]
Person [id=1, type=0, createDate=2020-08-18T12:26:15.616034800, code=BC, pay=1100.0]
```

Demo [here](https://onlinegdb.com/r1ScOeYfD)

Comment: Did you check the code? feel free to ask if you face any problem

Comment: Yes it seems like it works perfect. my only doubt is if there is a more maintainable and clear way to do this, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Quick way is to group by a map of the key fields:

```
 groupingBy(e -> Map.<String, Object>of(
    "id", e.getId(),
    "type", e.getType(),
    "createDate", e.getCreateDate(),
    "code", e.getCode(),
    "pay", e.getPay()
 ), identity())
```

Map's `equals()` method works as you would hope it does.

Comment: is not possible to access to the getId() and other properties with this approach

Comment: what do you mean? `map.get("id")` with return it

Comment: Just that I'm not able to access the properties of the class, by this way.